# How to compile and install a Linux kernel into an ARM kit

Tags: linux, embedded, arm, xenomai

I have an ARM kit beside me and a Linux kernel source code patched with Xenomai on my machine. I understand I can send data to the kit through an USB cable and a (windows-based, of course) software, but I'm stumped as to exactly *what* I should be sending that would make the kit run Linux.

(clarifications from comments: It is an Atmel AT91SAM9260-EK kit. It uses SAM-BA and SAM-PROG for the loading and unloading of data through either a serial or USB cable.)

Comment: Can you clarify what ARM kit you have?  In general, the process of getting Linux running on a ARM board involves making a bootloader for the board, preparing a Flash-based filesystem, and getting an ARM kernel to boot from the filesystem or Flash memory.

Comment: It is an Atmel AT91SAM9260-EK kit. It uses SAM-BA and SAM-PROG for the loading and unloading of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd start with the ATM91SAM9 Linux software package from Atmel and follow the instructions.

Linky:

http://www.atmel.com/dyn/products/tools_card.asp?tool_id=4335

Otherwise, you need to get GCC setup with an ARM back end on a Linux box, build a Linux binary and then figure out how to load it on the devt board.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out some cross compiler like [OpenEmbedded](http://wiki.openembedded.net/index.php/Main_Page) which will help you compile the kernel for the ARM architecture.

Answer (score 1):

i would suggest jtag and openOCD, then you just use the JTAG to place your filesystem and kernal image in the flash memory, in a place wear our bootloader can find it. you might have to change your bootloader.
another option is you might start up your micro, then insert a bootloading program into the RAM of the program then change the program counter to point at it.
that bootloading program can init the UART/USB then you have a host side program that transers the files. this method is very complicated and generally only good if you don't want to spend 100$ on a jtag (hint, buy a jtag they are useful)